# AlarmManager effect on battery for an Alarm clock app

Tags: java, android

I want to built a **alarm clock** app for android
I'm using an AlarmManager that starts a service every 1 seconds to check system time.
now I have 3 question:

1- Is there an other way to check system time every 1 second? and what is the best way for this work?

2-what is this my way on battery charge? is it cause to reduce battery charge very faster?

3- what mechanism use the **android alarm app** for checking time?

please help me to built this app

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use the AlarmManager functionality supplied by the OS, and not try and invent this yourself.  Basically this allows you to make a call to a service at a predetermined time (probably ultimately what you want to do).

What you suggest would be very problematic for battery, and doesn't sound like a good approach.

Comment: now what is your solution? please explain more. how to call a service after a specific time?

Comment: Research: AlarmManager Example

Comment: Did you mean  that I change AlarmManager repeat time for each alarm that user sets?